# .NET Zip Class Increase Archive size?

Tags: c#, zip, azure-blob-storage

Created a large (compressed) zip file on content in a directory. The result file is not a multiple of 512 bytes, so am looking to add a "spacer" text file that is uncompressed to increase the file size. I don't see that in the Zip class docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.createentry?view=net-7.0) so was wondering if anyone could share a strategy to make that happen. Or an alternative idea to make the final zip the exact size I need (looking to upload to a page blob in Azure).

Thanks.

Comment: When you add a file to a zip there is both an directory entry and a file entry.  You would need to calculate both.  The better way is to add padding at end of file. See para 4.6.10 : https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng - you should put your comment as an answer. One thing I would add is either keep the number of padding bytes or the size of the original zip in blob's metadata so that when reading the blob, one only reads the original zip contents and not the entire blob.

Comment: Sounds like X-Y problem to me... Are you sure there is any problem to use the resulting "file" if you simply pad the space with 0? I'm pretty sure ZIP format knows where actual files  end and will ignore extra bytes even in real file...

Comment: Why does the length being a multiple of 512 matter?

Answer (score 0):

A zip file can store a comment up to 64K in length in the end-of-central-directory record. If you have Info-ZIP's zip command available, the `-z` option will add a zip file comment. You can size the comment to pad out your file length to an exact multiple of 512.

winzip, winrar, and pkzip all also have options to add an archive comment.